# Drill down charts for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, zedgraph

My employer has asked me to create some web pages with various charts - one of the requirements is to have a click through ability for further detials. I am looking for sugestions on chart libraries that I could use.

c#, .net 2.0

UPDATE:

I used zedgraph with a imagemap
[drilldown Sample](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Use_an_ImageMap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [**ZedGraph**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/).

Seems to be a bit stale in terms of active development, but it may give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The free [**ASP.NET Charting controls**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx) support clickable regions.  You can set a URL for individual data items.

As long as you don't mind wiring all this up, you'll be fine.  If you want the drill-down to happen automatically, you'll want something more powerful.

Comment: Thanks. I am still stuck in .net 2.0 and the charting controls require .net 3.5

Comment: I wasn't aware of the 3.5 dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx :-)